# Tooltip stopped working for Google timeline chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, timeline

I was using google charts API since last few weeks but since yesterday tooltip stopped working for timeline chart. I have line charts for which tooltip works but somehow only timeline charts seems to be affected by this.
Here is the function which creates chart for me:

```
drawTimelineChart : function(rows, elementId) {
    if(elementId == undefined || elementId == ''){
        elementId = 'day';
    }
    var container = document.getElementById(elementId);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);

    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({
        type : 'string',
        id : 'DateAndBatch',
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
        type : 'string',
        id : 'TargetTable',
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
        type : 'date',
        id : 'Start',
    });
    dataTable.addColumn({
        type : 'date',
        id : 'End',
    });
    dataTable.addRows(rows);
    var options = {
        timeline : {
            groupByRowLabel : false,
        }
    };
    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
```

When I look into DOM I can see following node is being inserted in DOM whenever I hover over the timeline blocks but tooltip is not visible on the page.

```
<div class=​"google-visualization-tooltip" style=​"width:​ 240px;​ height:​ 112px;​ left:​ 424px;​ top:​ 11.472000000000008px;​ pointer-events:​ none;​">​
```

Can someone tell me how to debug & fix this issue?

Comment: I would start by checking where the focus of your mouse is when you have your timeline charts. I'm guessing you will need to make sure you can focus on them.

Comment: Do you have a test page or a full code example that demonstrates the problem?  I can't replicate it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the culprit after lot of debugging but could not get correct reason.

So, actually I am using [Twitter bootstrap UI panel](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) in my page and when I put my timeline chart inside panel body, it doesn't work. Here is markup:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Timeline<span class="dateInfo"></span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body" id="day" style="height: 1350px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

but if I remove "panel-body" class from the div in which I am rendering my chart, it starts working. Looks like some CSS issue but I can't pin point what. So this is the code which works:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="panel panel-primary" style="width: 700px;">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h3 class="panel-title">
                    Timeline<span class="dateInfo"></span>
                </h3>
            </div>
            <div id="day" style="height: 1350px;"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Anyways its a good GOTCHA for chart developers if they are using Bootstrap framework.